# How are YAML files used in ROS?

Tags: ros, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I searched and couldn't find. I would like to know what are YAML files for in ROS and how to use them? Examples or tutorials would be great.
I have read about the YAML format used in command lines and that is not what I am asking.
Specifically I have a system developed in ROS and it has YAML files and I want to understand its use.

Oh and also, are they still used in ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356580/how-are-yaml-files-used-in-ros?/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2020-07-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Kansai,

YAML files are usually used in ROS to load Node configuration parameters in the [ROS Parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server). There are several ways lo load a YAMLfile in the parameter server:

You can load the file with the command line:

```
rosparam load my_cfg.yaml
```

**Note**: If you want to know more about `rosparam` take a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam).

You can also use this YAML file from a launch file with the `rosparam` tag:

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find my_pkg)/my_cfg.yaml" />
```

**Note**: If tou want to know more about this feaure check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam), and if you do not know what `roslaunch` you can check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch).

Then, after loading the file in the parameter server you will be able to get any parameter from there.

With command line:

```
rosparam list # List all ROS parameters
rosparam get /my_parameter # Get my_parameter value
```

But the most interesting part is that you can do this programatically generating a specific configuration for your node. Both `roscpp` and `rospy` have functions to deal with parameters, with `get`, `set`, `search`... instructions.

For instance if you have a C++ node and you want this node to have a configurable rate, you can load your rate in the parameter server:

```
rosparam set /node_rate "20.0" # or with yaml a file.
```

and retrieve this parameter in the node with:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
double rate;
nh.getParam("node_rate" , rate);
```

even you can set default params if the parameter is not found in the server with:

```
nh.param<double>("node_rate ", rate, 10.0);
```

The python API is very similar so If you want to know more about roscpp you can check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server), for python [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server).

As for your last question, of course it is used in ROS2 since it is a very powerful tool to generate any kind of configurable enviroment.

The main difference is that in ROS2 there is no "global parameter server" since all parameters are "owned" by individual nodes. Apart from that, the idea is very similar, although function usage are a bit different.

You can learn more about command line tool for ROS2 parameters [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Parameters/Understanding-ROS2-Parameters/) and how to use it programatically here: [C++](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Using-Parameters-In-A-Class-CPP/) and [Python](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Using-Parameters-In-A-Class-Python/).

Hope this helped you solving your doubts about this topic.

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-07-07**:
This is a beautiful answer, with complete explanation and all helpful links. Thanks for going out of your way to be so helpful and make this community better!

**Comment by [karry3775](https://answers.ros.org/users/53272/karry3775/) on 2020-11-15**:
This was wonderfully put.

**Comment by [noob_nerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/145224/noob_nerd/) on 2023-04-12**:
Really helpul. now I am able to connect things .Thanks!